# Hover over a button and highlight multiple controls when condition is met (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two buttons with commands bound to them.
If the user hovers over a button1 it should highlight (border color changes)
textbox1 and combobox1 only when the button1 is in disabled state.

If the user hovers over a button2 it should highlight (border color changes)
textbox2, textbo3 and combobox1 **only** when the button2 is in **disabled state**.

And finally unhighlight the controls on mouseleave.

Is this possible with pure XAML, because the style should be applied to other controls, not to the button itself who triggers the event and only when conditions are met? 
And how could this be done?

I found many examples on SO, but they do not apply to this specific case.

I started to do this programmatically:

```
<Button Name="btnGenerateHash"  
        IsEnabled="{Binding VM.IsGenerateButtonEnabled}"
        Command="{Binding GenerateCommand}"
        Content="{Binding VM.GenerateHashButtonLabel}" Width="160"                      
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding HighlightFieldsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source='generate,enter'}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding HighlightFieldsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source='generate,leave'}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Modified version:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
<CheckBox 
x:Name="EnableButton1CheckBox" 
Content="Enable Button1" 
Margin="4"
/>

<Grid Margin="4">

<Button   Click="button1_Click"
Content="Button1"
x:Name="button1"
IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=EnableButton1CheckBox}">

</Button>



<Border
x:Name="Button1MouseDetector"
Background="Transparent"
>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="MouseOver" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>


    <!-- 
When button1 is disabled, it can't receive mouse events, so we create a 
coextensive control that's explicitly transparent. If it merely had no  
background specified, it wouldn't get mouse events either. 
-->

</Grid>


<Grid Margin="4">
<Button  
Content="Button2"
x:Name="button2"
IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=EnableButton1CheckBox}">

</Button>



<Border
x:Name="Button2MouseDetector"
Background="Transparent"
>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="MouseOver" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>


    <!-- 
When button1 is disabled, it can't receive mouse events, so we create a 
coextensive control that's explicitly transparent. If it merely had no  
background specified, it wouldn't get mouse events either. 
-->

</Grid>      

<TextBox  
Text="tb1"
x:Name="tb1"
Margin="4"
>
<TextBox.Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition 
                Binding="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Button1MouseDetector}" 
                Value="MouseOver" 
                />
                <Condition 
                Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=button1}" 
                Value="False" 
                />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition 
                Binding="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Button2MouseDetector}" 
                Value="MouseOver" 
                />
                <Condition 
                Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=button2}" 
                Value="False" 
                />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Might give button1 a style with a trigger that sets Tag to something when mouseover, then give the other guys style multitriggers bound to button1.Tag and button1.IsEnabled. Similar deal for the others.

Comment: If you could provide some code that would be great. Dont want to type that much

Comment: @EdPlunkett, for you :-) lokusking was to quick :-).
But it should only be triggered when the button is in disabled state...?

Comment: @Legends If that was for me, see edit, oops

Comment: Yeah Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"

Comment: @lokusking, this is what I have so far, but going the programmatic way..
XAML only would be nice. I will try EdPlunkett's approach in the meantime..

Comment: @Legends I forgot something important: While button1 is disabled, it doesn't get mouse messages. So for my idea you need to have another control superimposed over it to get the mouseover.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, I think I will do it the programmatic way, I am not that proficient with XAML yet. So I can use any control (transparent) to superimpose the disabled button?
I will take a look at you answer...

Comment: @Legends See my answer; any control will do (note the bit about the background though). The superimposed thing is a bit ugly but you're going to need some variant on it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is partial, but illustrates how to

1. Expose mouseover state of a possibly disabled control to XAML style triggers on other controls, and
2. How those other XAML triggers can do stuff only when two different conditions are both true.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <CheckBox 
        x:Name="EnableButton1CheckBox" 
        Content="Enable Button1" 
        Margin="4"
        />
    <Grid
        Margin="4"
        >
        <Button 
            Content="Button1"
            x:Name="button1"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=EnableButton1CheckBox}"
            >
        </Button>
        <!-- 
        When button1 is disabled, it can't receive mouse events, so we create a 
        coextensive control that's explicitly transparent. If it merely had no  
        background specified, it wouldn't get mouse events either. 
        -->
        <Border
            x:Name="Button1MouseDetector"
            Background="Transparent"
            >
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="MouseOver" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
    </Grid>

    <Button 
        Content="Button2"
        x:Name="button2"
        Margin="4"
        >
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition 
                                Binding="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Button1MouseDetector}" 
                                Value="MouseOver" 
                                />
                            <Condition 
                                Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=button1}" 
                                Value="False" 
                                />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I am playing around with your sample, I have changed button2 to be a textbox. When I hover over button1 the border of tb2 turns red. I enter some characters into the tb and the mouseover effect is gone, it won't turn red anymore when I hover over button1.
One more question: Textbox2 can be highlighted, when hovering over disabled button1 and disabled button2 like mentioned in the post above.
How to bind also the Button2MouseDetector to textbox2? Textbox2 can be highlighted by both buttons.

Comment: @Legends With the textbox you may be seeing the `FocusVisualStyle` overriding the border you're setting -- what happens if you create a second textbox (or anything that can receive focus) and move focus to that? Or try setting FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" on the textbox and see if that changes it.

Comment: @Legends For the textBox2 style you'd have two triggers, the first one looking at Button1MouseDetector.Tag/button1.IsEnabled exactly as in my example, and another that's identical to the first except that it looks at Button2MouseDetector.Tag and button2.IsEnabled. That's how you do an "OR" in triggers: Just make a second trigger for the other condition.

Comment: I have created a second disabled button for testing. Struggling with how to apply the Button1MouseDetector to button1 and BMD2 to button2 in this grid. Only button1 triggers the highlighting when hovering over it. When I solve this, I will approach the focus issue.

Comment: This answer answers what i have asked for, so Ed, thank you very much for your patience and help !!!

Comment: @Legends post the whole current XAML, it might be something easy

Comment: Added the XAML, how to disable the border if the button is active? The click event of the button does not fire because of the overlay..

Comment: @Legends ohhh right! You'll have to give the border the trigger which hides the border by setting visibility to collapsed, when its button IsEnabled. Sorry, forgot that part!

Comment: Solved it like this, works perfectly:
` <Border x:Name="Button2MouseDetector" Background="Transparent" 
                    Visibility="{Binding ElementName=button2, Path=IsEnabled, 
                    Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityCollapsedInvertedConverter}}" `